# Enable SSH Root Login with Password in Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server, permissions, ssh

I'm trying to allow Root login on my ubuntu server but it just doesn't work. I tried googling for a while now and I only see things like "Set PermitRootLogin yes" but I tried that, saved and restarted and it still didn't work. Keep getting a "Permission denied, please try again". The password is 1234 (temporary) and I don't think I miss typed that this often.

I tried PermitRootLogin yes, UsePAM no, commented things out like StrictMode etc.

I am also able to login as root when I'm doing it on the ubuntu server itself.

Here is my sshd_config

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

Any ideas on what else I could try?

EDIT:
auth.log:

```
Dec  8 17:01:41 Testumgebung-Ubuntu login[1554]: ROOT LOGIN  on '/dev/tty1'

Dec  8 17:01:56 Testumgebung-Ubuntu sshd[1568]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.211.55.2  user=root

Dec  8 17:01:57 Testumgebung-Ubuntu sshd[1568]: Failed password for root from 10.211.55.2 port 58058 ssh2

Dec  8 17:02:12 Testumgebung-Ubuntu sshd[1571]: Accepted password for seb from 10.211.55.2 port 58060 ssh2
```

First message is from succesfull login on the ubuntu system, last one is login with user seb via sftp

Comment: You could try reading `man sshd_config`.

Comment: Checkout [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/817571/permission-denied-in-ssh-to-debian-8-5-using-root-user-although-permitrootlogin/817575#817575). If it does not work, please add `/var/log/auth.log` output here.

Comment: @SuB Okay I tried. Still noting. Also added auth.log

Comment: Probably wrong password?

Comment: Did you enable root account?

Comment: Doesn't seem like a duplicate question to me. This question is for 16.04. The other question is for 14.04. There are some minor differences. I ignored the other question in my search because I assumed it was out of date info.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove "#" from line "#PasswordAuthentication yes" then restart ssh service. It may resolve your issue.